# Trouble with using linear gradient in html selector

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

So I've never had an issue doing this before.

I have this:

```
html {
    background: linear-gradient (#1f7c65, #60d4ae);
}
```

It's doing nothing. Should be super straightforward. I've even stripped all other CSS to be sure there wasn't something else affecting it. So the above line is the only styling applied to the entire document.

If I add a

```
background-color: red;
```

It works fine.

When I look at the code in the in-browser console, it has the linear-gradient attribute struck through, as if there was an overriding problem.

I've cross-referenced with any other sites I've made that use gradients. The code block is identical. I've checked it against W3Schools, thinking maybe I'm just having a stupid day (it is Monday).

Tested in three browsers: Firefox, Chrome, and Safari (all most current update). Tested with both hex codes and CSS color names.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've failed to mention what the exact problem you're having is.

Comment: It might be the spacing, delete the space between the word gradient. and also uncomment the hex color.

Comment: The space fixed it. Wow. Never had a problem with a space before in CSS.

Comment: Yes css is anal about spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has to do with the spacing, delete the space between the word gradient. and also uncomment the hex color

Comment: Yep it was spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/9Y64N/1/

Comment: Not sure why it's showing as commented in my post.

Thanks for the solution!!